# Cypress: Check current URL

Tags: automation, cypress

I am trying to get URL which I am getting after redirection if do following:

```
  cy.url().then(url => {
    cy.log(url);
  });
```

Then I get logged initial URL, but not the (new url), how do I get url in cypress after redirection?
[redirection img (new url)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC3jn.png)

Solution:
To get the redirected URL just simply add cy.get and your element so it will wait until the redirect page loads. Here is the working solution for me:

```
  cy.get('.crumb > p')
  cy.url().then(url => {
    cy.log(url);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you wrote, you need to first wait for a element from the new URL to be visible, using a `cy.get('any-element-from-the-new-url')`.

After that you can get the new URL just using `cy.url()`, in this case if you want to log this URL you can just use `cy.log(cy.url())`.

Answer (score 0):

A more meaningful approach would be to add an assertion on the pathname to what you are expecting. The docs can shed some light on the `cy.location()`. You can use an include assertion on the pathname in the situation that you will not know all of the url string.

```
// visiting url - https://website.com/favorites
// redirects to - https://website.com/favorites/regional/local

cy.location('pathname') // yields "/favorites/regional/local"
  .should('include', '/favorites/')
  .then(cy.log)
```

Comment: Great thank you!

Also can do assertion for query parameters https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Check-location-for-query-params-and-pathname

Comment: Yes, however, that could be prone to change as opposed to the pathname.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, you don't have to do any previous step. Especially because the expectedUrl doesn't have to match the actual url which allow your test doesn't crash if that happens.

```
 cy.url('match', 'expectedUrl').then(el=>{
    cy.log(el)
 })
```