# how can I check the Url if it endsWith in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

when I start the tests I login then I go to the screen and then I need to assert some data then I need to make sure that the url ends with /details so I can run the other cases and use data from fixtures, but when I am in url phase in the test it turns into about:blank

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setDataAndSave', (criteria, clickTitle = true, saveNew = false, isTab = false) => {
      cy.url().then((url) => {
        cy.log('Initial URL:', url); // Log the initial URL before the wait
    
        cy.wait(5000); // Wait for a certain period (adjust as needed)
    
        cy.url().then((updatedUrl) => {
          cy.log('Updated URL:', updatedUrl); // Log the updated URL after the wait
    
          if (!updatedUrl.endsWith('/details')) {
            cy.displayInsertPage();
            cy.log('Navigated to insert page');
          }
    
          if (cy.containTabs()) {
            cy.browseTabs(cy.mapInputIdsWithTabs(criteria));
            cy.log('Browsed through tabs');
          } else {
            cy.setCriteria(criteria);
            cy.log('Set criteria');
          }
    
          if (saveNew) {
            cy.saveAndAddNewRecord();
            cy.log('Saved and added new record');
          } else {
            cy.saveRecord();
            cy.log('Saved record');
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: You can alternatively, use cy.location('pathname'). here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879093/cypress-check-current-url/71880553#71880553

Answer (score 1):

You Can check content of url , First call the function

> cy.url()

to get the url then use Assertion

> Should

to validate it contains the desired text.

```
cy.url().should('include','/details');
```